# How to insert Interstitial ad in Listview?

Tags: android

I am having trouble to put an interstitial ad in list view on click listener.
I am just stack into this i find an answer but none of those are doing well.I am trying but i can not find any error.

can anyone please tell me where is the problem & what is the Solution.

Here is my code

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
private PublisherInterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
                       ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView video;
    ImageView image;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
    // Get the position
    resultp = data.get(position);

    // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
    //rank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
    video = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
    // population = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);

    // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
    image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

    // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
    // rank.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.VIDEO_ID));
    video.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.TITLE));
    // population.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.DESCRIPTION));
    // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
    // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.THUMBNAILS), image);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-4265785833148880/6768099054");
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    displayInterstitial();
                }
            });
        }

        public void displayInterstitial() {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }
            else {


                // Get the position
                resultp = data.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, PlayerViewDemoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("videoId", resultp.get(MainActivity.VIDEO_ID));
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
    });
    return itemView;


}
```

oh last thing i got a java.lang.NullPointerException in logcat.

here is the logcat

```
12-09 22:15:27.675 26726-26726/com.nextappsbd.banglanatok2015 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.nextappsbd.banglanatok2015, PID: 26726
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                at com.nextappsbd.banglanatok2015.ListViewAdapter$1.displayInterstitial(ListViewAdapter.java:101)
                                                                                at com.nextappsbd.banglanatok2015.ListViewAdapter$1$1.onAdLoaded(ListViewAdapter.java:95)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzc.onAdLoaded(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzo$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.t.c(SourceFile:152)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.a.o(SourceFile:771)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.x.o(SourceFile:386)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.a.b(SourceFile:405)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.b.b(SourceFile:149)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.p.a.a(SourceFile:125)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.p.m.a(SourceFile:102)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.p.a.a(SourceFile:91)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.u.c.e(SourceFile:398)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.u.c.onPageFinished(SourceFile:374)
                                                                                at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onPageFinished(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:475)
                                                                                at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClient$AwWebContentsObserver$1.run(AwContentsClient.java:73)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5344)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:676)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Hello can you please check `data.size();` data is not null ? or can you please post entire log cat ?

Comment: define your ad outside of onclick method. `mInterstitialAd` is null in `displayInterstitial`. Try not to implement extra function to show ads

Comment: can u please give me an example